Is there a chess learning roadmap from beginner to the advanced level?
Is there a roadmap for step-by-step learning from beginner to advanced level? I want to evade aimless study.

No matter which path you follow. it will only work if you combine it with regular tournament play and analysis of own games, preferably without an engine.
Prefer longer time controls to shorter. In the beginning even 10+5 may be long enough, but at some point you will plateau if you don't introduce serious tournament play, that is 90+30 time control. The golden rule is: if you want to improve your blitz chess, improve your rapid chess. If you want to improve your rapid chess, improve your standard chess.
In the beginning you will progress the fastest by studying tactics. A very good, free, and gentle introduction is Predator at the chessboard by Ward Farnsworth.
I recommend you to finish this first and then practice tactics using the Lichess tactics trainer, only then proceeding to other resources
in this answer.
In the mid-range you will get most progress from studying classical games. Get any annotated game collection written by a player you like. My favourites are Geller's Applications of chess theory and Gligorić's I play against pieces.
Books
If you prefer books to videos, you have two very well-respected options:
The steps method
The chess steps method was developed in the Netherlands and has full curriculum from 800 to 2100 Elo.
Build up your chess
Training course in 9 volumes by Artur Yusupov (world champion Anand's trainer). It provides a training plan from 1500 to 2100 Elo. This curriculum is a bit harder than the step method.
Videos
Here I recommend you these youtube channels:

GM Daniel Naroditsky, especially his speedruns. Danya plays over the rating range, explaining typical mistakes at each level, and gives tips how to improve.
IM Andras Toth's videos are more like small self-contained lessons, covering everything from calculation, amateur mindset, to opening study.
GM Alex Colovic has plenty of classical game analyses and insights from his own practice.

